# how to access Graphics object outside paintComponent() method

Tags: java, swing

Given these methods inside a class extending JPanel:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    }

public void drawLabels(LinkedList<Label> labelList) {

        for (Label l : labelList) {
            // drawString(l.getContent(), l.getX(), l.getY());
        }

    }
```

How would I go about accessing the Graphics element from
paintComponent() inside drawLabels()? I have seen (numerous)
remarks about not dealing with Graphics objects outside of
the paintComponent() method, but I can't get my head around
an alternate solution.

Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have calling `drawLabels`? paintComponent should call it and pass in the `Graphics`

Comment: Can't you call drawLabels() from paintComponent() and pass in the Graphics reference?

Comment: Sorry. As I mentioned below, drawLabels() is invoked in another class where it gets passed the LinkedList. That's why I'm having such a hard time figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I go about accessing the Graphics element from paintComponent() inside drawLabels()?

You don't try to access the Graphics object directly.

You invoke the `drawLabels()` method from inside the `paintComponent()` method and then you can pass the Graphics object to the drawLabels() method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        drawLabels(g, labelList);

    }

public void drawLabels(Graphics g, LinkedList<Label> labelList) {

        for (Label l : labelList) {
            // drawString(l.getContent(), l.getX(), l.getY());
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention that drawLabels() is invoked in another class, where it gets passed the LinkedList. Am I approaching the entire problem wrong?

Comment: `Am I approaching the entire problem wrong?` Yes. If you want to change the data that is painted on a panel then you should have a "setter" method to set the data. Then the setter method will save the data and invoke repaint(). The repaint() method will then invoke the paintComponent() method so the panel can be repainted. This is the way all components work and why, for example, a JLabel has methods like setText(), setFont(), setForeground(), setBackground()...

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.